# Writing better Swift code

Tags: swift

The title is on how to write better Swift code but, my real question is really what is better if I create a function, then call it when the button is clicked vs I write what I want to happen once the button is clicked .
Eg.

```
var thing = 0

func hi(){

    // Do something
    thing++
}

@IBAction func somethingHi(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(hi)
}
```

vs

```
var thing = 0

@IBAction func othersomethingHI(sender: AnyObject) {

    thing++

    println(thing)
}
```

I know both do the same thing but, is one "better" written than the other?

Comment: Your first code sample is incorrect. Did you mean to make `hi` return some value? Did you mean to call `hi`?

Comment: @Rob Yes I meant to call the hi function and no it didn't matter if hi returned any value. I was just wondering which one looked "cleaner" and whether one had a better purpose than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `IBAction` does something that you might want to do at some other time then it should call a function that performs that action, so that "others" can effect the same thing without duplicating code. If not, implement it solely in the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you're code is short and won't be reused, you can just put it inside the `@IBAction func` function.